# preg_match exclude a number

Tags: php, regex, numbers, preg-match, regex-negation

I have this code

```
preg_match("/\bHTTP(.)+ (\d{3})/", $string)
```

In the last pattern I have to check for a 3 digit number that can be composed by any digit but should not create a number like `404` or `401`, how can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the negative lookahead assertion to ensure that the matched string does not have a `404` or a  `401` as:

```
preg_match("/\bHTTP(.+) (?!404|401)(\d{3})/", $string)
```

[Rubular Link](http://www.rubular.com/r/tfY42pVFsy)

Comment: works! if I get it right you check for the existence of 401 or 404 if they do the string doesn't match but since its not "mandatory" the regex will continue if not present. is this the only way or there's a way to actually write "3 digit number except this 3-digit number"? This seems more of a "workaround"

Answer (score 1):

explanation:

A **negative lookahead** `?!` looks for text that **does not match the specified pattern**.
A positive lookahead looks for a pattern to match but not to return.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

- `?!` do not match the following
  pattern
- `404|401` either `404` or `401`, so the `|` is used for alternatives

Comment: but this "?!" looks into the 401|404 pattern or the \d{3} pattern?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think it works like a subexpression without backreference, and when it doesn't find 404 or 401 it is successful, so the match is good and it continues with the rest.  If it does find one of them the match fails and it stops without executing the 3 digit search.

Answer (score 1):

The more values you want to exclude, the more complicated this will get, but

```
preg_match("/\bHTTP(.+) ([0-35-9]\d{2}|4[1-9]\d|40[0235-9])/", $string)
```

will match any three digit number that doesn't start with 4,

**or** any three digit number that starts with 4 but doesn't start with 40,

**or** any three digit number that starts with 40 but isn't 401 or 404.

Comment: thanks! wasn't there an expression to exclude, like "^"? In my mind I thought something like this was possible [0-9^404|401){3}.

Comment: [^0-9]  negates all characters in the range

Comment: `[^...]` will match any **single** character that does **not** match the `...` expression (including character classes so `[^XYZ\s\d]` for example matches characters that are not whitespace, not digits, and neither X, Y, nor Z). But it can't be combined with any other syntax to specify a concept like "matching one group of characters and not matching another group". That is, you can't do anything like `[\d^4]` to say "match a digit but don't match `'4'`.

Comment: [^404] means all characters except 4,0,4

Comment: The negative lookahead is easier to read and to add values to but this is a great solution if a negative lookahead is not possible